# How to install System 7.5.5 on a Macintosh SE/30 using floppies?

Tags: floppy-disk, apple-macintosh, mac-os-classic, operating-system, boot

I have a Macintosh SE/30 with a formatted Disk. I'd like to install the latest System 7 on it that will run. According to Wikipedia that should be 7.5.5. According to several sources Apple has made it available for free. Where can I find it and how can I get it onto 1.44MB floppies for installation (the mac has a drive that supports them)?

Comment: Apple used to maintain an FTP full of good old stuff, but they ditched it over a decade ago.  A real shame to see it disappear.  I've had success just scrounging around the interwebs.  For example, you might look at https://winworldpc.com/library/operating-systems and snoop around...

Comment: Should we assume that you aren't interested in the easier ways of creating a bootable/workable SE/30 system today with modern components, and just want to experience the original way with floppies and spinning hard disks?

Comment: Without additional hardware I the only I/O I have is floppy.

Comment: Installing from floppy is not actually all that bad.  I've done both System 7.5.5 and (IIRC) A/UX from floppy and both went smoothly.  Mind you, that was years ago so I could be mis-remembering.

Answer (score 6):

These used to be available at [ftp.download.info.apple.com](ftp://ftp.download.info.apple.com) but that site's been down for ages.  Most (possibly all) of the files previously hosted there are available [from archive.org](https://archive.org/details/download.info.apple.com.2012.11) either as a 7.4GB zip file or as [individual files](https://ia600501.us.archive.org/zipview.php?zip=/8/items/download.info.apple.com.2012.11/download.info.apple.com.2012.11.zip).

You'll probably need to start with System 7.5.3 then update to 7.5.5<sup>1</sup>.  Note that these assume you already have System 7 on your Mac though there is a work-around for older OSes<sup>2</sup>.  Since you're it sounds like you're dealing with a bare system you'll also need to find a way to write the disk images onto physical floppy disks.

<sup>1</sup> These files can be found, e.g., under the following paths (replace "English-North_American" or "English-International" with the desired language):

- download.info.apple.com/Apple_Support_Area/Apple_Software_Updates/English-North_American/Macintosh/System/Older_System/System_7.5_Version_7.5.3/
- download.info.apple.com/Apple_Support_Area/Apple_Software_Updates/English-North_American/Macintosh/Full_Installs/System_7.5_Version_7.5.3.part/
- download.info.apple.com/Apple_Support_Area/Apple_Software_Updates/English-North_American/Macintosh/System/System_7.5.5_Update/
- download.info.apple.com/Apple_Support_Area/Apple_Software_Updates/English-International/Macintosh/System/Full_Installs/

<sup>2</sup> From one of the readme files:

> This software is available as 19 parts of a self-mounting Disk Copy
>   image. Download all 19 parts to your hard drive and then double-click
>   on the first part to mount the compressed disk image on your desktop.
>
> Note that self-mounting Disk Images require Mac OS version 7.0.1 or
>   later. If you are using a version of Mac OS prior to this, you can
>   download the System 7.5 Network Access floppy disk and boot your
>   Macintosh from that to use this software.

Comment: I would strongly recommend System 7.1 over 7.5.x because 7.1 is more stable, and comes on many fewer floppy disks. I did install 7.5.5 from floppies and it took a long time. Mostly I don't like 7.5 because there are a lot more bugs than 7.1 and it can't run that many additional programs on a 68k Mac. System 7.6 is even better but can't run on the SE/30.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm still looking for a way to get the initial image onto floppies.

Comment: There are instructions that may work on a Mac: https://lowendmac.com/2008/creating-classic-mac-boot-floppies-in-os-x/
I'll see if I can hack something together for other systems. I mean who even uses modern Macs?